# Why are the codes generated by $G$ and $[I_k \mid A]$ equivalent?

Tags: coding-theory

I am using the monomial equivalence definition for the equivalence of linear codes, so two codes $C, C'$ are called equivalent if there is a monomial matrix $M$ such that $ C'=CM=\{cM : c \in C\}$.
Now I am trying to understand why for every $[n,k]$ code $C$ with some $k \times n$ generator matrix $G$ there exists an equivalent code $C'$ generated by $[I_k \mid A]$ where $I_k$ is the identity matrix and $A$ an $k \times (n-k)$ matrix.

I know that the matrix $[I_k \mid A]$ can be derived from $G$ by way of Gaussian elimination. This is done by multiplying elementary matrices to $G$. Now two types (those giving row-switching and row-multiplying operations) of elementary matrices are also monomial. But row-addition elementary matrices are not. If the linear codes generated by $[I_k \mid A]$  and $G$ are indeed monomially equivalent, then there must exist monomial matrices such that the rows of $G$ multiplied to these monomial matrices give the rows of $[I_k \mid A]$.

So I have some questions: How does is that possible if there are non-monomial row-addition elementary matrices involved? Perhaps it is possible to write the elementary matrices as a product of monomial matrices (I do not think so)? How do I prove the existence of monomial matrices fulfilling the above property?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**edit:**

I now learned that Gaussian elimination is not always enough to obtain one matrix from another.
But in short, my question still is:
Van Lint says: It is well known from linear algebra that every linear code is equivalent to a code with generator matrix in standard form. Could anyone elaborate the reasoning in this statement?

Comment: That is true, I must have misunderstood something then. But how can I reason that the Codes generated by $[I_k\mid A]$ and $G$ are monomially equivalent? There then are even more operations involved, I am not sure if they can be even performed by monomial matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume here that the alphabet $\ \Sigma\ $ of your codes is a field.

Note that $\ M\ $ is an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix which operates on the *columns* of $\ G\ $.  If $\ E\ $ is a $\ k\times k\ $ elementary matrix, the codes $\ \big\{x^TG\,\big|\,x\in\Sigma^k\big\}\ $ and $\ \big\{x^TEG\,\big|\,x\in\Sigma^k\big\}\ $ are not merely *equivalent*, but *identical*:
$$
\big\{x^TG\,\big|\,x\in\Sigma^k\big\}= \big\{x^TEG\,\big|\,x\in\Sigma^k\big\}
$$
because $\ E\ $ is invertible.  For the result you're asking about to hold, the rowspace of $\ G\ $ must have dimension $\ k\ $—i.e. it cannot have any redundant rows.  Since its column space must also have dimension $\ k\ $ then among its $\ n\ $ columns there must exist $\ k\ $ that are linearly  independent. Let $\ M\ $ be a permutation (and hence monomial) matrix such that $\ GM \ $ has $\ k\ $ linearly independent columns shuffled to the first $\ k\ $ positions.  There must now exist an invertible $\ k\times k\ $ matrix $\ V\ $ such that $\ VGM=\big[I_k\,\big|\,A\big]\ $ for some $\   k\times(n-k)\ $ matrix $\ A\ $.

Now if $\ C'\ $ and $\ C\ $ are the codes generated by $\ VGM=\big[I_k\,\big|\,A\big]\ $ and $\ G\ $, respectively, then $\ C'=CM\ $, and therefore $\ C'\ $ and $\ C\ $ are equivalent.

Comment: This was very helpful and enlightened some essential linear algebra I had long forgotten. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the definition of equivalence, you are multiplying the monomial matrix with the code C, not just with its generating matrix G.

Indeed, the key to the answer is that a linear code is identified with a linear subspace (such as C), not with a basis of that subspace (the rows G). The matrix G gives one particular basis, but all linear combinations of rows of G are codewords too! Rows of G can always be added "for free" simply because the code is linear.

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that point! I assume this answers my question in conjunction with Morgan Rodgers's above comment, as permuting columns can also be done by monomial matrices.